# Access Powershell via Visual C++ (API)

Tags: c++, windows, powershell

I'd like to write a program that effectively "pipes" Powershell, so that I can send commands and parse the responses in C++, without actually opening the prompt on the screen.

Any tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can certainly do this but you'll need to use managed code as PowerShell's architecture is based entirely on the CLR object model.

I'm not sure of the C++ syntax but you can start with the [PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell.aspx) class in System.Management.Automation.dll and use its static [Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell.create.aspx) method to create an instance to which you can pipe data and run commands.

Comment: Note that you could also create a managed DLL specifically for this and use one of [the solutions here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719985/calling-managed-c-sharp-functions-from-unmanaged-c) for calling it from unmanaged C++.

Answer (score 4):

I have an answer that might solve your problem although it is not literally an answer to the question you asked.

Well, what I need in my current project is a system call that does not open a window and that does give me the opportunity to read out the results written to standard-output or standard-error.

In case you can live with that - here is some code from the before-mentioned codebase:

```
public class RsbSystem
{
    string command = null;
    string param = null;
    string commandLine = null;
    public int ExitCode = 0;

    //..

    /// <summary>Exec for apps that don't want console output</summary>
    /// <param name="msg">returns output of called program</param>
    /// <returns>0 if ok</returns>
    /// <remarks>RsbSystem instance keeps the result in member ExitCode</remarks>
    public int Exec(ref string msg)
    {
        var p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = command;
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = param;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.Start();
        if (!p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            msg = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        if (!p.StandardError.EndOfStream)
            msg += p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit(120000);  // this needs to come after readToEnd() RSB: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx
        ExitCode = p.ExitCode;
        p.Dispose();
        return ExitCode;
    }

    // ..

    public RsbSystem(string cmdLine)
    {
        commandLine = cmdLine;
        var pos = 0;
        if (cmdLine[0] == '"')
            pos = cmdLine.IndexOf("\" ") + 1;
        else pos = cmdLine.IndexOf(" ");
        command = pos > -1 ? cmdLine.Substring(0, pos).Trim() : cmdLine;
        param = pos > -1 ? cmdLine.Substring(pos + 1).TrimStart() : "";
    }
}
```

Also: please forgive me that the code is in C# instead of C++.

As you can see it calls any program - and does not use PowerShell. If that's already a workaround for you - fine. If not, you might consider calling the Powershell from the commandline using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724940/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-from-the-command-line-and-pass-a-directory-as-a-p) and possible get where you want to be that way.

Hope it helps or at least gives you an idea.