# How to run a Powershell script from the command line and pass a directory as a parameter

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

```powershell
PowerShell -Command .\Foo.ps1
```

- `Foo.ps1`:

  ```powershell
  Function Foo($directory)
  {
      echo $directory
  }

  if ($args.Length -eq 0)
  {
      echo "Usage: Foo <directory>"
  }
  else
  {
      Foo($args[0])
  }
  ```

  Despite `Foo.ps1` being in the directory from where I am calling Powershell, this results in:

  ```
  The term '.\Foo.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
  Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
  ```

  - *EDIT: Wasn't working because PowerShell was changing directory due to `profile.ps1` containing `cd C:\`*

I then tried to call it specifying the full path to the script file, but no matter what I try, I can't get it to work. *I believe I have to quote the path because it contains whitespaces, as does the file name I need to pass in an argument to the script.*

- Best guess so far:

  ```powershell
  PowerShell -Command "'C:\Dummy Directory 1\Foo.ps1' 'C:\Dummy Directory 2\File.txt'"
  ```

  Outputs error:

  ```
  Unexpected token 'C:\Dummy Directory 2\File.txt' in expression or statement. 
  At line:1 char:136.
  ```

Comment: You can also use -NoProfile when you call powershell from the cmd.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

try this:

```
powershell "C:\Dummy Directory 1\Foo.ps1 'C:\Dummy Directory 2\File.txt'"
```

Answer (score 57):

you are calling a script file not a command so you have to use -file eg :

```
powershell -executionPolicy bypass -noexit -file "c:\temp\test.ps1" "c:\test with space"
```

for PS V2

```
powershell.exe -noexit &'c:\my scripts\test.ps1'
```

(check bottom of this technet page http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx )

Comment: The Windows PowerShell 1.0 Owner’s Manual has been retired. For the most up-to-date Windows PowerShell content, go to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help#-file-filepath-parameters

Answer (score 31):

Using the flag `-Command` you can execute your entire powershell line as if it was a command in the PowerShell prompt:

```
powershell -Command "& '<PATH_TO_PS1_FILE>' '<ARG_1>' '<ARG_2>' ... '<ARG_N>'"
```

This solved my issue with running PowerShell commands in Visual Studio Post-Build and Pre-Build events.

Answer (score 3):

Add the param declation at the top of ps1 file

**test.ps1**

```
param(
  # Our preferred encoding
  [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
  [ValidateSet("UTF8","Unicode","UTF7","ASCII","UTF32","BigEndianUnicode")]
  [string]$Encoding = "UTF8"
)

write ("Encoding : {0}" -f $Encoding)
```

**result**

```
C:\temp> .\test.ps1 -Encoding ASCII
Encoding : ASCII
```

Answer (score 2):

**Change your code to the following :**

```
Function Foo($directory)
    {
        echo $directory
    }

    if ($args.Length -eq 0)
    {
        echo "Usage: Foo <directory>"
    }
    else
    {
        Foo([string[]]$args)
    }
```

And then invoke it as:

> powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "c:\foo.ps1" "c:\Documents and Settings" "c:\test"

Answer (score 0):

you have type and hit enter :

PowerShell -Command