# Add functionality to access vba with c# (or c++/cli)

Tags: c#, c++, vba, excel

I need to add new functionality to vba in access. I already tried a lot of tutorials:
http://www.office-loesung.de/ftopic268792_0_0_asc.php (german) and 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/555660/Extend-your-VBA-code-with-Csharp-VB-NET-or-Cpluspl (cant post more cause of rep)

but none of them works for me. The customer has office 2013 and i am using .net 4.5.

We want to provide the customer a rest api which is already written in c#/.net and which needs some encryption dlls of the .net world.

I tried to create an dll with "Interop COM" switch on and could add a reference of the dll to my VBA test Sheet BUT neither objects nor static test functions have been working. There even is no intelisense in VBA. A restart of the program did not solve the problem either. (though somehting went wrong before)

The error message i retrieve is "Runtime Error 429 - ActiveX Component Can't Create Object" (for my own code as well as for the code from codeplex (with all modules, C#, VBA, C++/Cli))

Is there any other way to go, adding new functionality to VBA / extending it with own functions?

Comment: What specific functionality are you trying to add?  I realize yours is a more general question, but if you could detail specifically what you are trying to do then maybe there is a "stop-gap" that could be done.

Answer (score -1):

Okay so I finally found a way myself.

In this post [calling managed c# functions from unmanaged c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719985/calling-managed-c-sharp-functions-from-unmanaged-c) there is the NuGet Package Unmanaged Exports linked. 
So I created a new C# DLL Project, inserted for testing purpose following code:

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    internal static class Class1
    {
        [DllExport("square", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        static Double Square(Double dateValue)
        {
            return dateValue * dateValue;
        }

        [DllExport("test", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        static String Test()
        {
            return " ok";
        }

        [DllExport("mytest2", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        static void Test4(String doSomething)
        {
            // Manipulate (and obisously create new) String
            doSomething += " ok";
        }
    }
}
```

Compiled this with x64 switch on, and created an VBA Sheet in excel with:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function square Lib "C:\Users\<Name>\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\x64\Release\ClassLibrary1.dll" (ByVal dateValue As Double) As Double
Private Declare PtrSafe Function test Lib "C:\Users\<Name>\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\x64\Release\ClassLibrary1.dll" () As String
Private Declare PtrSafe Function mytest2 Lib "C:\Users\<Name>\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\x64\Release\ClassLibrary1.dll" (ByRef dateValue As String)

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim zahl As Double
    zahl = CInt(TextBox1.text)
    zahl = square(zahl)
    Label1.Caption = CStr(zahl)

    Dim text As String
    text = "This is"
    mytest2 (text)
    MsgBox text
End Sub
```

The only error I still get is when calling the test function. Returning an string seems to break excel. (Program instantly quits) But I think that should be solved in another question.